# how load javascript from local computer in pyside qwebview?

Tags: javascript, python, pyside, qwebview

my files

```
messi_fan.py
barcelona_fan.html
jq.js
```

in same directory.

**messi_fan.py**

```
        f = open('barcelona_fan.html', 'r')
        html = f.read()
        f.close()
        self.webView = QWebView()
        self.webView.setHtml(html, baseUrl=QUrl('http://local'))
        self.webView.show()
```

**barcelona_fan.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "jq.js"></script>
```

my problem is jquery not loading in Qwebview. if i use like this in barcelona_fan.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

everything would work. but i want to load .js file from local.How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

Let the baseUrl look to the local directory:

```
path = "c:\\foo\\bar"
self.webView.setHtml(html, baseUrl = QUrl().fromLocalFile(path))
```

BTW: if needed, don't forget:

```
self.webView.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)
```